# FetchError: invalid json response body at https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/hashvaluereason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, rest

when I requesting the data it gives the below error:

FetchError: invalid json response body at https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/Qmc79GYqhAvU1qpDCJ4Ji37fWt2EoerqqxHb7e7bxakkFX reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at E:\MEDIBLOCK\backend\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:273:32
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async Object.getDataFromIPFS (file:///E:/MEDIBLOCK/backend/controller/auth/ipfsServices.js:57:20)
at async getAllDoctors (file:///E:/MEDIBLOCK/backend/controller/auth/doctorController.js:147:24) {
type: 'invalid-json'
}

code:

```
const doctorInfo = await fetch(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}/doctor/allDoctorInfo`,
      { mode: "cors" }
    );
    const response = await doctorInfo.json();

async getDataFromIPFS(hash) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/${hash}`,
        { mode: "cors" }
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log( error);
    }
  },
```

```
  async getAllDoctors(req, res, next) { 
    try {
      const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(hospitABI, contarct_address);
      const allAddress = await contract.methods.getDoctorAddresses().call();
      let allInfo = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < allAddress.length; i++) {
        const doctor = await contract.methods
         .GetDoctorByAddress(allAddress[i])
          .call();
        allInfo = allInfo.concat(doctor);
      }

      const info = [];
      for (let i = 1; i < allInfo.length; i++) {
        console.log(allInfo[i]["0"]);
        const result = await ipfsServiceController.getDataFromIPFS(
          allInfo[i]["0"]
        );
        result.phoneNo = allInfo[i]["1"]; 
        info.push(result);
      }
      res.send(info);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("main -> " + error); 
    }
  }
```

I am try to get the data but it gives the error and express app gets crashed!

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Comment: Seems valid JSON, `{"name":"sdfsdf","email":"df@","gender":"Male","age":"34","hospital_name":"asdfsdf","specialization":"Ophthalmology","degree":"MS","DOR":"2023-06-01"}`

Comment: can you elaborate it